# How to make a "New text document" entry in the context menu?

Tags: windows, context-menu, right-click

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add Notepad to Right-click new menu in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/438011/add-notepad-to-right-click-new-menu-in-windows-7)

There is no entry for `New > Text document` in the context menu when I right click.
[image: right click of mouse]

How can I add an entry for `"text document"` in the `New` menu?

Answer (score 4):

Probably some registry cleaner destroyed the related registry setting. Download [this zip file](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/229494d1346571183-new-context-menu-remove-restore-default-menu-items-text_document_new_context_menu_item.zip) (the last download link on [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/28677-new-context-menu-remove-restore-default-menu-items.html) page) and double click on the `Restore_Text_Document_New_Context_Menu_Item.reg`.

Comment: link to zip is down

Comment: updated the links.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_tweaks.htm), create a new text document (by opening notepad, of course), paste the following

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory] @="File Folder" "AlwaysShowExt"="" "EditFlags"=dword:000001d2 "InfoTip"="prop:DocComments" "BrowserFlags"=dword:00000008

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\New] @="{D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt] @="txtfile" "PerceivedType"="text" "Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\PersistentHandler] @="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew] "NullFile"=""
```

save it, choose "All file" as type, use .reg extension, run it, and restart your computer