# Windows Context Menu - New > RTF Document - But with Page Layout margins set to Narrow or Custom?

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, context-menu, templates

Let's say I leverage the info in these following answers..

- ["New Word Document" missing from right-click context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/439005/new-word-document-missing-from-right-click-context-menu)
- [How can I add an item to the 'new' context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/34704/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-the-new-context-menu)
- [How to make a "New text document" entry in the context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/258632/how-to-make-a-new-text-document-entry-in-the-context-menu)
- ["Create new text document" option missing from context menu](https://superuser.com/questions/629813/create-new-text-document-option-missing-from-context-menu)

to creat a "New RTF Document" menu item to Initiate/ Invoke creation of a RTF Document.

---

**How, can I get "Word 2010" and "Write/ Wordpad" to default to do so, using a Narrow (0.5) or Custom Page Layout?**

---

- I know I can change Margins after opening the document. But to do it every time for every New RTF is too much effort.
- Also, I know there are some "Default" templates/ mechanisms that Word defaults to when it creates a New Document

But I am not sure if and how I can leverage them to work/ apply when a file's created via the context menu "New > RTF Document"?

- Current OS: Win 8.1 Pro - 6.3 Build 9600
- Microsoft Office 2010

**Update: Export from Registry key for RTF:**

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.rtf] @="Word.RTF.8" "Content
>   Type"="application/msword" "PerceivedType"="document"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.rtf\OpenWithList]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.rtf\OpenWithList\WordPad.exe] @=""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.rtf\OpenWithProgIDs]
>   "calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.RTF"=hex(0):
>   "calibre64bit.AssocFile.RTF"=hex(0):
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.rtf\PersistentHandler]
>   @="{2e2294a9-50d7-4fe7-a09f-e6492e185884}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.rtf\ShellEx]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.rtf\ShellEx{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}]
>   @="{84F66100-FF7C-4fb4-B0C0-02CD7FB668FE}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.rtf\ShellNew]
>   "ItemName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,\
>   69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,\
>   00,20,00,4e,00,54,00,5c,00,41,00,63,00,63,00,65,00,73,00,73,00,6f,00,72,00,\
>   69,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,57,00,4f,00,52,00,44,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,\
>   00,58,00,45,00,2c,00,2d,00,32,00,31,00,33,00,00,00 "Data"="{\rtf1}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.rtf\Word.RTF.8]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.rtf\Word.RTF.8\ShellNew]

Comment: That's a great question. It can be done only if you've associated `.RTF` files with Winword, instead of Wordpad. Pl confirm which program you've associated `.RTF` files with.

Comment: Right now it's associated with word as office 2010 was installed and word took over the association. But curious if it's at all doable on system without word/ office and only Wordpad. Does Wordpad use a default kinda thing like word?

Comment: WordPad simply ignores the page layout meta data stored inside the RTF, and uses the default margin settings for all documents. Whereas Winword respects it and uses per-document page layout settings.

Comment: Then please guide me how to do this for word RTF

Answer (score 2):

**Create a sample .RTF file using Microsoft Word**

Create a RTF file using Microsoft Word, with the desired margin settings and page layout options. Save the file as `template.rtf` in the following folder:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Templates
```

**Backup .RTF file type settings**

Open a Command Prompt window, and run the following command to backup the existing .RTF file type settings:

```
reg export hkcr\.rtf  %userprofile%\desktop\rtf_fta.reg
```

This creates a file named `rtf_fta.reg` on your desktop.

**Apply the REG fix below**

Copy the following contents to Notepad and save the file with .REG extension, let's say `rtf_template.reg`. Double-click the file to apply the settings in the registry.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rtf]
@="Word.RTF.8"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rtf\Word.RTF.8\ShellNew]
"FileName"="template.rtf"
"NullFile"=-
```

That's it. When you create a new .RTF document from the right-click menu, it uses `template.rtf` as the source or template file, and the newly created file will have the same page layout settings as the source.

This above applies only if you open .RTF files using Microsoft Word.

**Note:** After running the REG file, you may in some cases need to re-associate .RTF file types with Microsoft Word using the `Open with` dialog.

Comment: I will try this out over the weekend and get back

Comment: Updated with Export of RTF Reg key: 
So, the Word Doc/x template is Normal.dotm - Should the template for RTF be .RTF or something else (better naming syntax) Or It kind of doesnt matter due the registry entry pointing to that file? - Also, found this - I'm wondering if this is extraneous or has some usable info here: http://rtftemplate.sourceforge.net/userguide/design-rtfmodel/msword.html

Comment: Word Templates vs ShellNew Templates - both are different things. Simply create and customize the file named `template.rtf` - and place in that location... that should be enough.

Comment: Ah! Interesting, I thought there was some linkage here. So/ but I still have to create a "New RTF Document" in the context menu here.. using the above posted links or your answer is complete does it automatic? PS: I didnt see a New RTF item on the Context menu

Comment: Yes, you create a new .RTF document as usual from the `New` menu -- The new RTF file will now use the same settings as the template file.

Comment: Ok :) I saw it on the Menu - Your "NullFile" is slightly different than this - http://superuser.com/a/34706/183467 But does it create the same data in registry and mean/ have the same meaning? PS: Wondering if its possible to "order" that "New Context Menu" ? Allow RTF be next to the Word and text document "new items"

Comment: Mine removes `NullFile` and instead adds `Filename`. Regarding sorting, I'll have to test it further.

Comment: Last issue: I am getting the RTF document but its not picking up the margins from template.rtf - currently 0.3 - Could that be an issue? Should I try with 0.5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43992/discussion-between-w32sh-and-alex-s).

Answer (score 1):

My system = Windows 10 Pro/64bit.
What worked for me:-
I placed my default RTF template in:

"%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\"

I called my template file:

```
   "RTF_Windows_Template.rtf"
```

I edited the following Registry Key (I did not touch the key's default value.
); add the key if it is missing:

```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rtf\ShellNew
```

I added/edited the following entry under this key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rtf\ShellNew Name:FileName; Type:String (REG_SZ); Data: RTF_Windows_Template.rtf
```

I added/edited the following entry under the same key (I did not enter anything in its Data Value):
    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.rtf\ShellNew Name:NullFile; Type:String (REG_SZ)

The result when using the background context "New" menu was that "Rich Text Document" appeared and the resulting new file was based on my template.

I hope this is of use to others.

Comment: Is there a general template location I can point to so I can add a new blank visual studio solution file?